# Improving Speed of VBA Code - Copy/paste two sets of variable, Excel does a calculation, returns a value then copy/paste the output value

Tags: performance, beginner, vba, excel, macros

I am attaching the code here. I am very new to VBA and trying to do a complex calculation using Macro. Please help me improve the speed of the attached code. The code works fine and produces the end output. The program is intended to do the following. I am calling the below two subs after data is filled in the sheet.
Copy and paste two sets of variable in two specified cell
Excel does a complex calculation using FILTER command & other INDEX and MATCH Formulas
Copy and paste the output to a location
This is required to done 1500 times for two sets of data. Present execution time is 10 minutes.

```
Sub CF_Amb_Pr_NG()
Dim intX As Integer
Dim copyRng As String
X = 43
For X = 40 To 1539
    Sheets("CC_NG_APr").Select
    Range("C2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R" & X & "C2"
    Range("C3").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R" & X & "C3"
    Range("E2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Let copyRng = "D" & X
    Range(copyRng).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
Next X
End Sub

Sub CF_RH_NG()
Dim intX As Integer
Dim copyRng As String
X = 33
For X = 32 To 1531
    Sheets("CC_NG_RH").Select
    Range("C2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R" & X & "C2"
    Range("C3").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R" & X & "C3"
    Range("E2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Let copyRng = "D" & X
    Range(copyRng).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
Next X
End Sub
```

[image: Calculations used in for determining E2' using values for C2&C3`]

Attached screenshot of sheet in formula mode to explain what exactly is going on in `E2` based on the values fed in `C2` & `C3`. Basis the value entered in `C2` & `C3`, formula to be chosen to calculate `E2` is chosen and final value is shown. I need to get value in `E2` for 3000 sets of data in `C2` & `C3`

Thanks a lot for helping !

Comment: Did you post the whole code, or did you post too much ? I don't see where CF_RH_NG is actually used in this code.

Comment: The first procedure is missing the signature and possibly some additional lines of code.

Comment: @Anonymous - I am calling these two subs in the excel to perform calculation after data entry is completed. The calculations are done in two different sheets.

Comment: @FreeMan - Please help here. I am getting the result i need but it takes forever.

Comment: COM and Excel Automation is known to be slow.  Writing cell-by-cell is VERY slow.  Is there any way you can write to an entire range once rather than individual rows?

Comment: @RickDavin - Thanks Rick. I have tried to copy range in one go but couldn't manage as this would require the calculation excel is doing as a code, which I am unable to do.

Comment: One thing that will definitely help is to [avoid using `.Select`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: @FreeMan - Thanks ! Can you suggest an edit in the code in question to avoid using `.select`

Comment: That's a good question and answers for you to study and understand for yourself so you can recognize when you're falling into that path in the future. TBH, it looks like your code was generated by the Macro Recorder. There's nothing whatsoever wrong with that - it'll help teach you how things work. The other, _critical_ thing it will teach you is how to write _very crappy_ code. The MR is _not_ known for generating efficient code, it simply records each UI thing that you do - turn the MR on and hit `<down arrow>` a few times and see what it gives you!

Comment: @FreeMan - appreciate the advice. Will try to break my head around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As best I can tell, `Sub CF_Amb_Pr_NG()` sets cells `C2` and `C3` to formulas that changes with each iteration through the loop, then ends with them set to `"=R1539C2"`.

You then copy cell `E2` to each row in column `D` from 40 to 1539.

Unless there's something going on with the value in `C2` and `C3` that somehow impact `E2`, if you *really* want to stick with the `.Select` and `.PasteSpecial` this should do the trick:

```
Sub test()

  With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .Range("E2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    .Range("D40:D1539").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    .Range("C2").FormulaR1C1 = "=R1539C2"
    .Range("C3").FormulaR1C1 = "=R1539C3"
  End With

End Sub
```

Otherwise, I'd suggest this which is even easier:

```
Sub test()

  With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .Range("d40:d1539").Value2 = .Range("e2").Value2
    .Range("C2").FormulaR1C1 = "=R1539C2"
    .Range("C3").FormulaR1C1 = "=R1539C3"
  End With

End Sub
```

It copies `E2` to `D40` through `D1539`, then it sets `C2` and `C3` to the final values they have in your loop.

Make a similar change to `Sub CF_RH_NG()`.

---

*If* the value in `E2` changes with the values as determined in `C2` and `C3` for each iteration through the loop, I'd *strongly* suggest that you add a helper column (out in column `Z` or `LLL` or someplace) that calculates `E2` for the *current* row, then simply make the formula in `D40` read `=LLL40` (manually copy that formula down to `D1539` *one* time), and be done with it - no need for code at all.

---

These simple assignments should execute in a second or two (Excel is notably slow in copying in my recent experience), but significantly less than the 10 minutes you're currently experiencing.

---

Based on the update, a loop *is* required, avoiding `.Select` will still help performance:

```
Sub test()

  On Error GoTo CleanExit
'  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Dim row As Long
  For row = 40 To 1539
    With Sheet1
      .Range("C2").FormulaR1C1 = "=R" & CStr(row) & "C2"
      .Range("C3").FormulaR1C1 = "=R" & CStr(row) & "C3"
      .Range.Cells.Item(4, row).Value2 = .Range("e2").Value2
    End With
  Next
  
CleanExit:
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  
End Sub
```

Note in this case the `With Sheet1` - you can use the worksheet's `(Name)` property as a direct reference to it (you'll have to modify this for *your* `Workbook`):

[image]

Note that this is *not* the same as the `.Name` of the worksheet as displayed on the "tab":[image]

Additionally, I've added `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`, but left it commented out for now. Make sure your new code is working properly before enabling this. This will prevent Excel from refreshing the screen with each step it takes. Removing all the UI activity reduces the amount of execution time (it's not a panacea, though). Note the addition of the `On Error Goto...` to ensure that if anything were to go wrong during execution, it will reenable `ScreenUpdating`. If you don't weird and confusing things happen.

Comment: For info on `.Value` vs `.Value2`, see [this good SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359835/what-is-the-difference-between-text-value-and-value2).

Comment: I don't think this would work. See the thing is the formula to be used to calculate `E2` is dependent on the values fed into `C2` & `C3`. Based on the data in `C2` & `C3`, Formula to be used in `E2` is chosen and subsequently `E2` is calculated.

Comment: Then use the suggestion between the two lines - instead of calculating them in a function, have hard-coded calculations set off to the side somewhere in a hidden/locked column and let Excel just do its thing.

Comment: Added an image of the excel to explain what actually is going on in `C2` & `C3` to generate `E2`. I have tried using a helper column but could not make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot @freeman & the community !! Implemented solution by @freeman with the below with a single line change. Could not get to work the `.Range.Cells.Item(4, row).Value2 = .Range("e2").Value2` changed this to `.Range(pst_row).Value2 = .Range("e2").Value2` added one more variable `pst_row` rest it works like charm. Runtime < 10 seconds. Also disabled screen update.

```
Dim row As Long
  Dim pst_row As String
  For row = 42 To 1541
    With Sheet3
    Let pst_row = "D" & row
      .Range("C2").FormulaR1C1 = "=R" & CStr(row) & "C2"
      .Range("C3").FormulaR1C1 = "=R" & CStr(row) & "C3"
      .Range(pst_row).Value2 = .Range("e2").Value2
    End With
  Next
End Sub
```